# Glyphicons don't get displayed properly

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces, glyphicons

I am developing an application with jsf, primefaces and bootstrap 3.

The test page from glyphicons is perfectly displayed in my browser, but when I try to use the icons in the web project I only get weird symbols.

My best guess is that the glyphicons css file cannot find the fonts even though I copied them also into the project and let the relative pathes the same:

```
    -resources
     -css
      -bootstrap.css
      -bootstrap-glyphicons.css
     -fonts
      -glyphicons-halflings.eot
      -glyphicons-halflings.otf
      -glyphicons-halflings.svg
       ...
```

How can I make sure the css file finds my font directory / fix this error?

Comment: What does your HTML markup for the icons look like?

Comment: Its the same as in the example that you download with the glyphicons: <span class="glyphicon glyphicons-search"></span>

Comment: Did you try without the 's' on the end.. `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Resource Handler`, which is a standard mechanism for defining and accessing resources. I see that your resources are placed in the right way to do that.

Try replace the paths on your css for something like this

```
#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings.svg']}
```

Further information:

[What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

http://www.packtpub.com/article/jsf-images-css-and-js

Answer (score 5):

Inside `bootstrap-glyphicons.css` replace following strings:

- `src:url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot')`
  to
  `#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot]}`

---

- `src:url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot?#iefix')`
  to
  `#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot?#iefix]}`

---

- `src:url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.woff')`
  to
  `#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.woff]}`

---

- `src:url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.ttf')`
  to
  `#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.ttf]}`

---

- `src:url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')`
  to
  `#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular]}`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here.
Omnifaces has already solved that for us :)

[Omnifaces UnmappedResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler)

Here we have no need to modify third party resources at all.

Looks then like this:

```html
<h:head>
  <h:outputStylesheet name="glyphicons/web/html_css/css/glyphicons.css"/>
</h:head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';

src:url("#{resource['bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");

src:url("#{resource['bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),

url("#{resource['bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'),

url("#{resource['bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'),

url("#{resource['bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}#glyphicons-halflingsregular") format('svg')
}
```

Comment: esta es la respuesa correcta note que debe colocar el paquete si utiliza paquetes, y los parametros debe quedar por fuera del resurces

Comment: please use english and why don't you just include some explanations in your post instead of commenting on it?

Answer (score 0):

In Html Page:

```
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"></h:outputStylesheet>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"></h:outputStylesheet>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"></h:outputStylesheet>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"></h:outputStylesheet>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"></h:outputStylesheet>
```

In CSS (you can override the @font-face in another .css file and don't touch bootstrap.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url("#{resource['css:bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");
  src: url("#{resource['css:bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
       url("#{resource['css:bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'), 
       url("#{resource['css:bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'), 
       url("#{resource['css:bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format('svg');
}
```

General Use:

```
#{resource['<resource name>']}
```

or

```
#{resource['<library name>:<resource name>']}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most simple solution was to use **bootsfaces** and implement at least one element of bootsfaces in the page. Then all references to bootsfaces libs were loaded without any problem.
As I had too many layout and javascript problems with primefaces in combination with bootstrap, I replaced all primefaces elements with plain jsf and bootsfaces and some elements from richfaces.
Surely this is not a solution for every need, but it saved me a lot of time, as I do not have much knowledge in bootstrap and not much time to spend on css/js/html either.

Needless to say that more and more frameworks work seamless with bootstrap.